# Stop Dropzone.js from stripping exif data

Tags: asp.net, file-upload, dropzone.js

Is there anyway I can make dropzone.js keep the exif data with the image it's uploading?

I have an asp.net application that get's the date/time taken of a user uploaded image and has been working great using an asp.net fileupload control.

I'd like to implement Dropzone.js - but every file uploaded seems to be missing all of the exif data I was able to read via the fileupload control.

I've searched the repo/faq/docs and can't find anything relevant regarding exif data.

Answer (score 0):

EBKAC!  After removing Dropzone.js and attempting to upload the same images - I found out that the images I'm using DON'T have the info on them.  (I'm surprised as they are from an old phone)  So this issue has NOTHING to do with Dropzone.js